# How to check if SSRS Textbox is empty

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

How do you check if a textbox is empty in SSRS 2008?
I've tried this code and it doesn't work.

```
IIF(ReportItems!txtCountVolunter.Value = "", false, true)
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try the following:

```
=IIF(Len(ReportItems!txtCountVolunteer.Value) <= 0, true, false)
```

Comment: =`Len(ReportItems!txtCountVolunteer.Value) <= 0` is enough actually

Answer (score 20):

You should use this expression

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!UserEmail.Value) OR Fields!UserEmail.Value = "",
 "Empty", "Not Empty")
```

The first: IsNothing(Fields!UserEmail.Value) checks if the field value is NULL
The second: Fields!UserEmail.Value = "" checks of the filed value is blank ""

So you need both of them in order to check if the value is either null or empty.

Answer (score 3):

Try the IsNothing function like this:

```
IIF(IsNothing(ReportItems!txtCountVolunter.Value), "empty", "not empty")
```

Answer (score 3):

Check for null

```
=IIF(IsNothing(ReportItems!txtCountVolunteer.Value),true, false)
```

Answer (score 2):

While the answers before this are correct, they are a bit redundant. Just this will suffice:

```
=String.IsNullOrEmpty(Fields!txtCountVolunteer.Value)
```

To identify if the value is not empty:

```
=NOT String.IsNullOrEmpty(Fields!txtCountVolunteer.Value)
```

If you are using the expression to dictate visibility, keep in mind that the Expression should evaluate to true when the field should be **hidden** (it defaults to visible). It took me the better part of an hour troubleshooting my own expression before I realized that.

In my example, I am hiding the Lot Number if I have an empty or null string value: [Visibility Expression Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WD6g.png)

Answer (score 0):

For those who come from a .NET world and you want to check non-empty and say for argument sake want the value 0 instead of blank!

```
=IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ReportItems!txtCountVolunteer.Value), 0, ReportItems!txtCountVolunteer.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you use conversion and empty value in your dataset (I have stored procedure as source):

```
=CInt(IIF(Parameters!Seller_id.Value = "" , "-1" , Parameters!Seller_id.Value))
```

and then in stored proc add condition

```
([some_field]=@param or @param=-1)
```