# SSRS isnothing working on a whole, but there are insances where it is not picking up everything

Tags: reporting-services

I have an expressoin that works on a whole which is:

`=IIF((IsNothing(Fields!Hello.Value),".",Fields!Hello.Value)`

The only problem is that I have instances where it does not catch every blank. I have thought of using the "LTrinm" within the main statement. Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738569/how-to-check-if-ssrs-textbox-is-empty

Comment: I have double checked and there are fields which apear blank but do have something in the field thanks to @bamie9l expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IsNothing() checks if a value is null however, you are searching for a blank string. Strings which are "" or " " are not evaluated as null in IsNothing() and therefore are not caught - they have a value of empty or white space.

```
    =IIF(LEN(Trim(Fields!Hello.Value)) = 0,".",Fields!Hello.Value)
```

Sidenote: This is why in the .Net CLR there is a method for both IsNullOrEmpty() and IsNullOrWhiteSpace().